# Reading sentences as string inputs from users

Tags: c++, string, flush

I have been trying to implement a simple code which takes a sentence as an input from the user, stores it in a string and displays it back.

Here are the issues: 
1. When T = 1, the program exits immediately.
2. When T>1, the loop runs for only T-1 times.

I think the usage of cin to store the value of T is an issue here. Is the value of T entered being stored as a string due to some buffer capacity of cin?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
int T;
std::cin >> T;
while (T--)
{
    std::string song;
    getline(std::cin, song);
    std::cout << song << std::endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you terminate the input that becomes `T`? With a newline. What happens with that newline after you read into `T`? It's still left in the input buffer. What will happen when you next call `std::getline`, what is the first character it will read? The newline, and what happens next? The loop iterates and then `T` is zero (for the first case where `T` was originally `1`) and the loop and then the program exits.

The solution to this problem is to [ignore](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) characters up to and including the newline.

Answer (score 1):

This is a strange way to do it. So you ask the user to tell the program, before any other input, how many lines will follow? Why not simply:

```
std::string s;
while (getline(std::cin, s)) {
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

(This will simply echo every line (press enter to end the line) until end-of-file (`Ctrl-d`).

Either way, the problem with your code is the `while (T--)`: so why don't you try to see what your `T` is, and what your `getline` gives you on each iteration? (I will let you figure it out on your own). Why not use the idiomatic:

```
for (int i = 0; i < T; ++i)
```

?

P.S. If you want to read *sentences*, and not lines, you might want to consider reading up to a delimiter (for example `.`). `getline` will do that for you, too:

```
getline(std::cin, s, '.');
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a getchar after cin as the \n after the input of T stays in buffer.

```
std::cin >> T;
getchar();
```